# How do I cast a JavaScript object to a Kotlin object?

Tags: kotlin

I have received a JavaScript object in response to a remote HTTP request.  I have a kotlin model (trait) that defines the various fields I expect on the object (the nullable ones are optional).

First, I want to do an `is` check to make sure my object is in fact of the expected type.  I initially tried `payload is MyModel` but that doesn't work due to the way the `is` operator is written in kotlin.js.

Second, I want to cast to `MyModel` so I can get auto-complete, etc. on the object while I work with it.  Normally, the `is` alone would be enough but since that doesn't work I need something for this problem as well.

I would like to avoid manually populating my object from a `dynamic`.  I wouldn't mind doing this so much if I could use `by Delegates.mapVal(...)` but that requires a `Map<String, Any?>` and I don't know how to get my `dynamic`/`Any?` payload into a `Map<String, Any?>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) We don't have structure check for `is` in performance reasons. 
I don't sure that we need generic solution for this, but anyway I created [issue about it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6814), feel free to vote or star it to get updates.

2) `is` enough if you use [smart cast](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts), like:

```
if (payload is MyModel) {
// call MyModel members on payload
}
```

But don't forget about (1) :)

3) You can write something like:

```
class MapDynamic<out V>(val d: dynamic) {
  public fun get(thisRef: Any, desc: PropertyMetadata): V {
        return d[desc.name]
    }
}

class Foo(data: dynamic) {
  val field: Int by MapDynamic(data)
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  val f = Foo(object { val field = 123 })
  println(f.field)
}
```

But it looks too verbose, but You can add additional logic for e.g. when data don't have requested field. And if You don't need custom logic I think cast is enough.

Comment: I will try this when I get home, but from what I remember of my original issue, the `is` check in your #2 will fail.  If I remember correctly, the JavaScript generated from an `is` check verifies that the prototypes match, which they won't because all I have is a plain old JavaScript object with no prototype, just fields.

Comment: As I said in (1) we cannot check type structurally in performance reasons. I think generic solution will be costly.

Comment: Note for classes Kotlin's `is` uses JS's `instanceof`.

Comment: Using Kotlin 0.10.947 and using a `data class Foo`, and a `payload: dynamic`: When I do `if (data !is Foo) ...` it compiles down to `if (!Kotlin.isType(payload, _.mypackage.Foo)) ...` which resolves to `function(a, b) {
    return null == a || null == b ? !1 : a instanceof b ? !0 : null != b && null == b.$metadata$ || b.$metadata$.type == c.TYPE.CLASS ? !1 : h(a.constructor, b);
  }`  I don't know JavaScript well enough, but ultimately the result is that payload (which is just a JSON object off the wire) never matches `Foo`.  For now, I'll just continue using `foo = payload as Foo`.

Comment: JS simple(JSON) object is instance of Object and it doesn't contain information for detect what type is it. So, as I say, we should check fields but common solution for that will be costly.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, the cast, you can do:

```
fun responseHandler(payload: dynamic) {
    val myModel = payload as MyModel
}
```

or

```
fun responseHandler(payload: dynamic) {
    val myModel: MyModel = payload
}
```

This will throw an NPE if payload is null, but it won't actually validate that the payload matches MyModel.  In particular, you may end up with null fields/properties that shouldn't be if the payload was missing those fields/properties.

Comment: This doesn't exactly work either as `myModel` won't have the methods I need on it like it would if I had a real `MyModel`.  On top of that, equality checks against enums in `myModel` will fail.